# React DatePicker 12AM to 12PM

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

i'm using this plugin in my react app.

https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

i'm using date format like that:

```
dateFormat="MM/d/yyyy hhaa"
```

my hours in hour picker starting with 12 AM end finish at 11 PM

After 11 PM i wan't to add to list 12 AM just for users can directly select after 11 PM to 12 AM

Adding 12 AM to hours picker i already did:

```
injectTimes={[setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 24), 0)]}
```

with this code i have now 2 12 AM in my hour picker but 12 AM it's putted to top how i can change order and put new 12 AM to under of 11 PM ?

Comment: 12PM would be noon, after 11:45PM would be 12AM

Comment: Sorry i explained not so good so 12.00 AM i wan't to add end of the time picker so for users who wan't to choose from morning to midnight. Actually 11 pm is 23:00 so after that i wan't to add 24:00 like 12PM

Comment: @user3348410 please edit your question and let me know what exactly you want